# Select all from table where the rows has the highest id of all those with the same foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a posts table with a author_id foreign key and a published status (bool).

I want to select all the most recent (highest id) published posts for an author (all those with the same author_id foreign id).

Right now I can get the highest for a group of foreign keys

```
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Posts WHERE  published = 1 AND author_id = 5);
```

But this only returns the highest id for a given foreign key. How would I write this to return all the posts with the highest id in their foreign key group?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT: Had it tagged with sql-server and mysql. It's mysql. Sorry about that

EDIT: Some asked for clarity 
Here is a sample of what I'm looking for:

`id      body                  author_id     published
1      Top 10...                  1             1
2      Breaking...                1             1
3      New Report..               3             1
4      Can Sunscreen...           3             1
5      Dow down...                2             1
6      Heart Warming...           2             1
7      Next time...               1             1
8      New study...               3             0`

So what i want to do is grab the posts with ids 4, 6, and 7 because 4 is the most recent (highest id) for author 3, 6 is the most recent for author 2 and 7 is the most recent for author 1. I also have the conditional of published which is why we don't grab 8 because it is 0.

`4      Can Sunscreen...           3     1
6      Heart Warming...           2     1
7      Next time...               1     1`

Answered: 
With a slight tweak to Igor Quirino answer by adding an IN instead of =, i think the following works:

SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Posts WHERE published = 1 GROUP BY author_id);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `IN` operator instead of `=` operator

The `IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in a WHERE clause.

The `IN` operator is a shorthand for multiple OR conditions.

```sql
IN Syntax
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

or:

```sql
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (SELECT STATEMENT);
```

The `IN` operator allows you to use a query that returns multiples records (your query must return exactly one column)

```sql
SELECT * FROM Posts WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Posts WHERE published = 1 GROUP BY author_id);
```

Happy to Help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I'll look into grouping it. But right now I'm getting Subquery returns more than 1 row.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the most recent posts for an author, use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  For instance, to get the 10 most recent posts for author 5:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.author_id = 5
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Thanks! But how would i do this for all authors? I'm trying to get the most recent post for all authors.